# Hook and curve transformation

Tags: bezier-curves

I do not know English very well and write via Google translator, but I need your help.

I need that bezier would retain its shape of a semicircle when I bind the last and the first vertex to different objects.

You can do it manually, but I would like some kind of automatic process, and it will be more accurate than me, thanks in advance :)
[image]

Comment: Make one curve, then copy it with hooks selected

Comment: I can not correctly describe the problem, it is necessary that the attached form of the biseuser maintains the clear form of the semicircle, but thanks for the help :)
 The problem is not solved yet :(

Comment: To clarify, can it be assumed Z is up for the semicircle and both ends are at Z=0?  If so a hook in middle driven such that its z location is half the distance that the other two are apart (eg circle diameter) should do it.